# How to mock imported component in cypress with Vue

Tags: vue.js, mocking, cypress

I have spent quite a lot time trying to mock imported component in the Cypress Component Testing.

Consider we have a `Parent.vue` component:

```
<template>
  <ChildComponent />
</template>

<script setup>
  import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue';
</script>
```

`ChildComponent.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div data-cy="child">Child</div>
</template>
```

How can we mock it the cypress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## React

Before I go to the answer, there are several articles that can come in handy for React users. The first link has worked for me:

1. https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/stub-react-import/
2. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/master/npm/react/cypress/component/advanced/mocking-imports
3. https://sinonjs.org/how-to/stub-dependency/

I have added additional rule to the webpack:

```
// cypress.config.js

devServer: {
  framework: 'create-react-app',
  bundler: 'webpack',
  webpackConfig: {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: false,
    module: {
      rules: [
        // application and Cypress files are bundled like React components
        // and instrumented using the babel-plugin-istanbul
        // (we will filter the code coverage for non-application files later)
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
              plugins: [
                // we could optionally insert this plugin
                // only if the code coverage flag is on
                'istanbul',
                [
                  '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
                  { loose: true },
                ],
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
},
```

And in `Parent.js` I have mocked `ChildComponent.js` as following:

```
import Parent from './Parent.js';
import * as ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.js';

it('mocks', () => {
  cy.stub(ChildComponent, 'default').returns(<div data-cy="child">MockedComponent</div>');

  cy.mount(Parent);
  cy.contains('[data-cy=child]', 'MockedComponent');
});

it('works without mock', () => {
  cy.mount(Parent);
  cy.contains('[data-cy=child]', 'Child');
});
```

## Vue

If we want to mock the component in Vue, we don't need any changes in the webpack, instead of mocking the default import we need to mock `render` function, and to suppress execution of script tag in the mocked component, we can mock `setup` function.

**Example:**

```
import Parent from './Parent.vue';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue';

it('should mock', () => {
  cy.stub(ChildComponent, 'setup').value(() => {});
  cy.stub(ChildComponent, 'render').value(() => <div data-cy="child">MockedComponent</div>);

  cy.mount(Parent);
  cy.contains('[data-cy=child]', 'MockedComponent');
});
```

### Mocking js module:

If you want to mock js module default export, you will need to do the same modification to the webpack config as for React above.

```
import * as jsModule from './jsModule.js';

it('should be mocked', () => {
  cy.stub(jsModule, 'default').value({
    someProperty: 'newProperty',
  });
});
```

### Mocking a function

To mock just a function of the module, you can use `returns` or `value`;

```
import jsModule from './jsModule.js';

it('should mock with returns', () => {
  cy.stub(jsModule, 'innerFunction').returns('MockValue');
});

it('should mock with value', () => {
  cy.stub(jsModule, 'innerFunction').value(() => 'MockValue');
});
```